# Rewrite URL to Remove Query String Variables

Tags: php, regex

I have a query string search engines still go to that contains several get variables. An older version of the query string used to have even more variables.

Instead of return a 404, which my site currently does when those old variables are included, I am trying to have the URL rewritten to remove the variable and ANY values it may (or may not) have entirely and in any order it may appear.
So I want

http://example.com/page?var1=123&var2=abc&var3=xyz
http://example.com/page?var2=890&var1=123&var3=xyz
http://example.com/page?var1=123&var3=xyz&var2=
http://example.com/page?var1=123&var3=xyz&var2=q

to become

http://example.com/page?var1=123&var3=xyz

This would go on an application page that already redirects incoming traffic.

Note: I do not have access to the page being called nor .htaccess.

Comment: *and in any order it may appear.* - have example?

Comment: In the example above, I want var2 to be removed completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this single rule to remove `var2=` query parameter from anywhere in query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*&)?var2=[^&]*&?(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=302,NE,L]
```

Comment: As I said above, I don't have access to the .htaccess file

Comment: Then find the admin who has access to it and ask him to use this rule

Comment: I am using nginx and my hosting provider limits access to any config files

Comment: I can probably suggest nginx equivalent rule as well but you need to be able to place it in nginx config file to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `preg_replace` function:

```
$url1 = "http://example.com/page?var1=123&var3=xyz&var2=";
$url2 = "http://example.com/page?var1=123&var2=abc&var3=xyz";

function removeParam($url, $param){
    $url = preg_replace("/&?var2=[^&]*/", "", $url);

    return $url;    
}

print_r(removeParam($url1, "var2"));  // http://example.com/page?var1=123&var3=xyz
print_r(removeParam($url2, "var2"));  // http://example.com/page?var1=123&var3=xyz
```

Comment: Will that also remove the param if it is null (e.g. http://example.com/page?var1=123&var2=&var3=xyz) and/or the last param (e.g. http://example.com/page?var1=123&var3=xy&var2=890)

Comment: @tcam27, sure, it will work for those cases. Just try